# Jquery Scrollable, is it possible to customize it with a scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

Jquery Scrollable is a tool by Jquery Tool that scrolls a list of images/videos

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/

But I am just wondering, has anyone of you tried to customize it with a scroll bar. What I mean is we want to use Jquery scrollable for the following page

http://www.space.ca/Face-Off.aspx

But we want to keep the scroll bar in the bottom, rather than using the left and right arrow to scroll through the video carousel.

Would that be possible? If you have done a customization of JQuery Scrollable and using the scroll bar , Please share some tips with me

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could archive this using plain css:

```
<div class="scrollMe">
    <div>Do what ever you want</div>
</div>
```

And then just make sure you css is in order:

```
.scrollMe {
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     white-space: nowrap; /* this is important for you, this means that you will keep everything in a single line which will make this guy scroll on the y-axis. If you need multiline on the childs you need to set: white-space: nowrap; on the childs  */
}
```

And all your block level childs needs `display: inline-block;`:

```
.scrollMe > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```